# Closing a circuit when a GPIO pin is low

Tags: transistors, gpio

I have a GPIO pin that reports when an accessory is connected to the device: the pin is high when there is no accessory and low when an accessory is connected. When an accessory is connected, I would like to close a circuit between a lead (0.5V@2.5μA) and ground.

The GPIO pin is 0.4V@1.6mA when low and I believe around 3.4V when high (the spec sheet doesn't say). There is also a voltage source around 3.7V.

Would a transistor be appropriate to act as a switch? From my research I believe a MOSFET could work well (compared to BJT) as it is toggled with voltage and doesn't draw a lot of current, is that right? One approach I came up with is to use a differential amplifier to subtract the GPIO pin's voltage from Vcc:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXuwcF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The op amp subtracts the GPIO pin's voltage from Vcc to flip the high and low states.
- When the GPIO pin is low, the op amp applies 3.3V to the MOSFET's gate, connecting Vin to ground.
- When the GPIO pin is high, the op amp applies 0.3V to the gate, below the MOSFET's Vgs threshold, opening the circuit.
- `Rin` and `Rf` have the same resistance values so the op amp doesn't amplify the voltage and are 1kOhm so that there's enough current to charge the transistor gate in a few hundred nanoseconds.
- `R1` and `R2` also share resistance values and are 100kOhm so the GPIO pin doesn't draw too much current and drain the battery.
- Do these resistor values make sense? Do there need to be any diodes (e.g. to prevent current from flowing into the GPIO pin) or capacitors to make the circuit better?

Am I on the right track or is there a simpler way to accomplish the original goal of connecting Vin to ground when the GPIO pin is low?

Comment: Tipp: If this is an actual product sold, check if what you doing is not patent protected... e.g. in case of a Automation Control System US2012043378A1 might apply. [patents trivial things very clever: any electomangetic procedure is covered.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you- the first transistor diverts base current from the second when the input is higher than about 600mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4mPzV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will reduce the voltage at the collector of Q2 to maybe 10 or 20mV. If you want it lower than that, you can replace Q2 with a 2N7000.

Comment: The circuit posted by the threaded started would also work, right? I just want to know.

Comment: @varun No, it won't work. The output voltage of the op-amp will always be railed 'near' GND (how near depends on the op-amp -- there is heavy loading of 2K to 3.7V on the output, and not all op-amps work on 3.7V, but regardless of that it will always be railed. The GPIO would have to exceed 3.7V for it to have a hope of budging.

Comment: what if Rin = R1 = 5K and Rf = R2 = 10K. So Gain here would be 2. And GPIO will be connected to the inverting terminal of Opamp and Vcc will be connected to the noninverting terminal. 
When GPIO = 0.4V opamp output = 2* (3.7-0.4) ~= 6V (Transistor ON)
WHen GPIO = 3.4V Opamp output = 2* (3.7-3.4)~= 0.6 (Transistor OFF)
Would this work?